# c# invokeMember click won't work

Tags: c#, click, webbrowser-control, invoke, invokemember

So I load a webpage, that has this in its html code:

```
<input style="margin-left: 140px;" name="e43X45asfaw4ybrZ34fi879234tg3e4eex" type="submit" id="submit" value="Begå kriminaliteten!" onmouseover="$('#ggg').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();">
```

and I use this to click it:

```
object o = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("e43X45asfaw4ybrZ34fi879234tg3e4eex")[0].InvokeMember("click");
            if (o != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("It worked!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("It didnt work!");
            }
```

and that code always leave it didn't work as well it didn't do anything to the webpage.

Here is my full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MafiaspilletRankeBot
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.Navigate("mafiaspillet.no");
            webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                timer1.Enabled = true;
                timer1.Interval = 15000;
            }
            catch {
                timer1.Enabled = false;
                MessageBox.Show("Timer error", "Looks like there a error");
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            timerun.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("brukernavn")[0].SetAttribute("value", textBox1.Text);
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("passord")[0].SetAttribute("value", textBox2.Text);
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("login_buton")[0].InvokeMember("click");
            timer2.Enabled = true;
            timer2.Interval = 15000;
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://mafiaspillet.no/kriminalitet3.php");
            timer3.Enabled = true;
            timer3.Interval = 15000;
            timer2.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            object o = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("e43X45asfaw4ybrZ34fi879234tg3e4eex")[0].InvokeMember("click");
            if (o != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("It worked!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("It didnt work!");
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Bot finnished!", "YEEY!");
            timer3.Enabled = false;
        }
        int i = 0;
        private void runtime_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            i++;
            timerun.Text = i.ToString() + " Sekunder";
        }
    }
}
```

So my problem is that the `InvokeMember("click")` doesn't work in my `public void timer3_Tick`.

It's like it can't do anything, but I can't find the problem :/

Answer (score 0):

you need to processing in the function WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs

here full code

```
private void WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   HtmlElementCollection inputCol = this.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
   foreach (HtmlElement el in inputCol)
   {
       if (el.GetAttribute("type").Equals("submit"))
       {
           el.InvokeMember("Click"); 
           MessageBox.Show("It worked!");
       }
   }
}
```